# Connecting Hyperledger Sawtooth Client to a Hyperledger Sawtooth Validator on a different machine

Tags: docker, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have two Ubuntu servers in a corporate environment. My plan is to setup a Sawtooth Validator on one machine and Sawtooth Client on the other.

I am able to run both of them on the same machine.

How do I setup a client on another machine and connect it to my current validator setup. Are there any files I need to copy or any docker images to copy or is there any configuration that needs to be done?

All the blogs available online explain the setup of a client and validator on the same machine. I haven't come across any blog explaining the setup on different machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your client connect to the REST API on the remote machine.
The TCP port for the Sawtooth REST API is `8008`.
If, for example, your validator node is at IP address `10.0.0.100`, you connect to `http://10.0.0.100:8008`

The REST API URL is specified in your client source code. Many Sawtooth clients have an option to specify the REST API point. For example, the intkey CLI has a `--url` option, so you would use `intkey --url http://10.0.0.100:8008`

This assumes there is not a firewall on your host machine (in this example, `10.0.0.100`). If there is either disable it or (preferably) open up incoming TCP port `8008`.